# sails.log does not work when set migrate to safe

Tags: sails.js

When i set `migrate: 'safe'` in `config/models.js`, `sails.log` stopped printing to console. When i set `migrate: 'alter'` then everything is ok. The same thing applies to `console.log`

Is this because `sails.log` isn't supposed to work during production? If so, how can i log to console during production?

My `models.js`:

```js
module.exports.models = {

  schema: true,

  migrate: 'safe',
  
 }
```

**UPDATE 1**

I logged from my model blueprint api as followed:

```html
module.exports = {
    create: function(req, res){
        console.log('req.body');
        console.log(req.body);
        sails.log.error('req.body');
        sails.log.error(req.body);
        return res.status(200).send('HAPPY');
    }
};
```

When i send a post request, i received the 'HAPPY' return value with code 200. So there couldn't have been any errors.

**Update 2**

This also happens when i set `csrf: false` in `config/security`. I think this might be a bug and will report it to sails.

Comment: Can you show us where you're trying to log from? I think it's much more likely that other code just isn't running because some other error crops up or some condition is different.

Comment: I logged from blueprint api. I have already verified that i got the correct return message, so there couldn't have been any errors.

Comment: Are you expecting the logging when you "sails lift" (and your models are "migrated"), or are you posting the api once the app is running?

Comment: I am posting to the URL once the app is running. I have also tried GET another action unrelated to blueprint, the console did not print either.

Comment: Can you check what is `level` defined in `log.js`.